# Unable to insert queries to mysql Table in visual studio (python)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, visual-studio, pymysql

My code is working in Jupyter notebook but it is not working in Visual Studio Code. The code is in python.

Problem is in VS, the %s is not being treated as a string:
[image]

Whereas in jupyter notebook, it is like this:
[image]

In VS, it is not showing any error but it is also not inserting any data into mysql table.

The complete code for the same is as:

```
query = """INSERT INTO """+tb+""" (Name, Intro, Location, Job, About, Education, Skills, URL) 
                               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """                    

        for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
            Name = sheet.cell(i,0).value
            Intro = sheet.cell(i,1).value
            Location = sheet.cell(i,2).value
            Job = sheet.cell(i,3).value
            About = sheet.cell(i,4).value
            Education = sheet.cell(i,5).value
            Skills = sheet.cell(i,6).value
            URL = sheet.cell(i,7).value

            values = (Name,Intro,Location,Job,About,Education,Skills,URL)

            cursor.execute(query,values)

        print(cursor.fetchall())



 Output in VS: () #Empty table since nothing is inserted
```

My question is, how to insert data into mysql table in VS? In other words, how to remove the problem of %s in visual studio.

Please help!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine but it is somehow not inserting any data into the table.

Comment: Okay, I was able to solve this problem. fetchall() removes the data from the table.